# Rails Hashie output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

here is my problem, i get a variable from a request and store it in @response.

then i debug response, debug(@response), and get this output:

```
--- !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
results:
- !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
  id: '33098557'
  firstName: john
  lastName: star
  relationship: self
  photo: https://foursquare.com/img/blank_boy.png
  tips: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
    count: 0
  lists: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
    groups:
    - !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
      type: created
      count: 1
      items: []
  gender: male
  homeCity: mexico
  bio: ''
  contact: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
    email: jhon@hotmail.com
unmatched: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
  email: []
```

i can get the results by typing @response.results, and get debuged this:

```
---
- !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
  id: '33098557'
  firstName: john
  lastName: star
  relationship: self
  photo: https://foursquare.com/img/blank_boy.png
  tips: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
    count: 0
  lists: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
    groups:
    - !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
      type: created
      count: 1
      items: []
  gender: male
  homeCity: mexico
  bio: ''
  contact: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
    email: jhon@hotmail.com
```

but i cant get the inner attributes like the email or firstname, how can i access those attributes???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@response` is an instance of `Hashie::Mash`, while `@response.results` is an instance of `Array`, so you need to access the index of the array you wish to receive a result for.

```
@response.results[0].firstName
@response.results[0].contact.email
```

will return the values for `firstName` and `email` of the first result respectively. You can loop through the responses *(to get all results if there happens to be more than one)* with

```
@response.results.each do |result|
  result.firstName
  result.contact.email
end
```

If there's always only one `result` you can also access this with Ruby's `.first` method

```
@response.results.first.email
# ...
```

Comment: i get this error
undefined method `firstName' for #<Array:0x36f6060>

Comment: I edited my response; missed the debug symbol `-` signifying `results` as an `Array`.

Comment: Is there a way you can remove those `!ruby/hash:Mash`?